# Redirect HTTP from HTTPS causes duplication in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I have a simple redirect that forwards the user from HTTP to HTTPS, but when it does on the root URL (eg. `www.example.nl`), it forwards to the following:

`https://www.example.nl/example.nl//`

What's going on and how I can stop it?

My COMPLETE .htaccess filelooks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,NC,R,L]

RewriteRule ^sleek-yourself/share/([^/]*)$ /sleekYourself.php?share=$1 [L]

php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size  100M
```

I've tried changing the optional parameters at the end of the RewriteRule, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Do you have other rules?

Comment: @JonLin I've added the complete .htacess contents

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: What gives it if you use : `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,NC,R,L]` (`$1` instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}`) ?

Comment: @Zimmi That appears to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Zimmi's comment I fixed this by changing things to:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,NC,R,L]
```

Using `$1` instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}`